# How can I get LWP::UserAgent to cache connections?

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent

In a perl script I'm using LWP::UserAgent like this:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( keep_alive => 10 );
```

After doing `$ua->get` a few thousand times to fetch URLs from, say, https://example.com, I would expect `$ua->conn_cache` to have ten open connections.  But, if I use Data::Dumper and do:

```
print Dumper( $ua->conn_cache );
```

I see only one connection:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'cc_limit_total' => 10,
                 'cc_conns' => [
                                 [
                                   bless( \*Symbol::GEN1, 'LWP::Protocol::https::Socket' ),
                                   'https',
                                   'example.com:443',
                                   1638549871
                                 ]
                               ]
               }, 'LWP::ConnCache' );
```

Am I doing something wrong, or am I just misinterpreting what the dump of conn_cache is showing me?  For what it's worth, the URLs I'm fetching differ only in their query parameters.

**Edit:**
OK, I understand (see the answer below).  Thanks. I'll look into things like LWP::Parallel::UserAgent instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way to handle many **sequential** requests to the **same host** is to reuse a single persistent TCP connection to this host - and this is exactly what you see. More connections are needed if requests to the same host are sent in parallel instead sequential or if requests are sent to multiple hosts.

To check the latter just do requests to example.com and example.org - you'll end up with two entries in the connection cache, one for example.com and one for example.org.

Comment: All of the requests I'm making are independent, and I'd like to make many of them in parallel if possible.

Comment: @BryanWright: *"I'd like to make many of them in parallel if possible"* - that's a different question, the current one is answered. LWP::UserAgent does not support parallel requests itself, you need to either need to use threads for this or even based programming like possible with Mojo::UserAgent.

Comment: Or Coro "threads" + LWP::UserAgent by using [LWP::Protocol::AnyEvent::http](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Protocol::AnyEvent::http)